# Make the text field in search form optional

Tags: php, search

I've added some custom fields to my search form, which will be used more frequently than the original text field (`<input name="s" />`). However, the text field seems to be required to perform a search, and an empty value isn't enough.

Valid: `http://www.example.com/?s=foobar&max_price=500`

Invalid: `http://www.example.com/?s=&max_price=500`

Is there any way to get round this?

The HTML form is pretty simple:

```
<form action="/">
   <input type="search" name="s" />
   <input type="number" name="max_price" value="0" min="0" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does the code for your form look like?

Comment: I updated the question with the form, nothing particular.

Comment: Okay, I solved this by creating my own search function with `wp_query()`. It'd although be interesting to know if this is possible with the default search function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create my own search function with [`wp_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), it seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Can you edit to show your new search function?

Answer (score 0):

If the results page isn't using a GET function to actually use the "s" parameter from the URL, why couldn't you just set it as a default value (e.g., foobar) and make it hidden on the form?

```
<form action="/">
   <input type="hidden" name="s" value="foobar" />
   <input type="number" name="max_price" value="0" min="0" />
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```